# Property not set when using Task.Run

Tags: c#, wpf, task, task-parallel-library

Vendors is bound to a combobox

```
//This works, Vendor is set
LoadVendors();
Vendor = Vendors.FirstOrDefault();
```

I would like LoadVendors() to Run in a separate thread, however Vendor is not set. Can somebody help?

```
//Doesn't work, Vendor is not set!
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => LoadVendors()).ContinueWith((t) => Vendor = Vendors.FirstOrDefault());
```

**Vendors**

```
public ObservableCollection<Vendor> Vendors
    {
        get
        {
            return _vendors;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_vendors != value)
            {
                var oldVendors = new ObservableCollection<Vendor>(_vendors);
                _vendors = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Vendors), oldVendors, Vendors, true);
            }

        }
    }
```

**LoadVendors**

```
private void LoadVendors()
    {

            var vendors = DataHelper.GetVendors()
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => Vendors.Clear());
            vendors.ForEach(dcpV =>
            {                    
                DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => Vendors.Add(vendor));
            });
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Vendors));

    }
```

Comment: Both of your RaisePropertyChanged calls look kinda funny, are you using some library?

Comment: @nvoigt Indeed MVVMLight library [link](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/f88345df-bea6-aa85-4d3c-90b1cbded839.htm)

Comment: Do try to avoid setters for your lists / collections properties. You can use the `Add` and `Clear` methods if you need to change data. I can almost guarantee you that it will be easier to work with.

Comment: @Default thank you. Will take that into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `DataHelper.GetVendors` method on the background thread and do everything else back on the UI thread:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> DataHelper.GetVendors())
    .ContinueWith(task => 
    {
        Vendors.Clear();
        foreach (var vendor in task.Result)
            Vendors.Add(vendor);
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Vendors));
        Vendor = Vendors.FirstOrDefault();
    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Why is TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() necessary?

Comment: @mm8 you could greatly simplify this by using `await Task.Run(..)`

Comment: @JSteward: I don't know about "greatly" and it depends on the context. You can't in a constructor for example :) But I get your point.